# FindBugs: How to avoid "Unwritten public field" warning when using JPA meta model?

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api, findbugs

I've written quite a lot of DAO class and using the `JPA criteria API` and its meta model in them, like in this example:

```
@Override
public EntityA findByEntityB(EntityB entityB) {
  CriteriaBuilder builder = this.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<EntityA> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(EntityA.class);
  Root<EntityA> root = criteriaQuery.from(EntityA.class);
  criteriaQuery.select(root);
  criteriaQuery.where(builder.and(builder.equal(root.get(EntityA_.entityB), entityB)));
  return this.findByCriteriaQuery(criteriaQuery);
}
```

While running static code analysis, `FindBugs` throws the following warning:

> UWF_UNWRITTEN_PUBLIC_OR_PROTECTED_FIELD, Priorität: Normal
>
> Unwritten public or protected field: EntityA_.entityB
>
> No writes were seen to this public/protected field.  All reads of it will return the default value. Check for errors (should it have been initialized?), or remove it if it is useless.

As I use the meta model classes in nearly all of my queries this warning is thrown very often.

Is there any useful way to avoid these warnings? As we all know the meta model classes are just generated and their attributs are never written.

**I don't want to exclude the DAO classes from FindBugs sca** as I want to check these to maybe find other possible bugs!

Comment: You could add a `setter` for the field.

Comment: @StephenC the metamodel classes are generated within each build and their attributs are `static`

Comment: You can implement a getter for a `static`.  This doesn't need to be "good style" :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

- Modify the generator to add a (redundant) setter<sup>1</sup>.
- Implement a FindBugs filter (see http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html) to exclude that specific bug in specific classes or packages.  Or generally.

---

<sup>1 - The setter could potentially be declared as `private`.  There is a good chance that FindBugs doesn't check that the setter is called.</sup>

Comment: As it seems, that there is no programmatic way to avoid these errors,  but only ignore them I add a filter in my findbugs configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [How to suppress FindBugs warnings for fields or local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503001/how-to-suppress-findbugs-warnings-for-fields-or-local-variables).

You can extract a method and apply method level @SuppressFBWarnings to that method.

Comment: I want to avoid this warnings, not supress / ignore them.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue.I don't think it's a duplicate, it's linked to JPA meta model. I'm looking for a programmatic way to clean properly these warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Setter of these fields, then it's able to remove the FindBugs error message

Answer (score 0):

This is the code marking the violation:

https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/blob/267af9fe850a7637252a748f7ce3483fab80968c/spotbugs/src/main/java/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/detect/UnreadFields.java#L1000

After reading the code there are two suggestions:

1. Add a `@NotNull` to the field (This way the field find its way into the collection `writtenNonNullFields` and the violation is ignored).
2. A bad idea (but possible from the source) to place a native method in the dto class (`native void hi();`). But I do strongly not recommend that.

From the comments:

Suggestion **2** is a bad idea because:

> The native hack is relying on implementation specific behavior. The JLS states: "Additionally, an UnsatisfiedLinkError, a subclass of LinkageError, may be thrown if a class declares a native method for which no implementation can be found. The error will occur if the method is used, or earlier, depending on what kind of resolution strategy is being used by an implementation of the Java Virtual Machine (§12.3).". "Earlier" could mean when the "class" is initialized ... which could be problematic if the native method has no native implementation at that time. (StephenC)

I tried both and both works fine (Suggestion 2 only in my current jvm).

Comment: The `native` hack is relying on implementation specific behavior.  The JLS states: *"Additionally, an UnsatisfiedLinkError, a subclass of LinkageError, may be
thrown if a class declares a native method for which no implementation can be
found. The error will occur if the method is used, **or earlier**, depending on what
kind of resolution strategy is being used by an implementation of the Java Virtual
Machine (§12.3)."*.  "Earlier" *could* mean when the "class" is initialized ... which *could* be problematic if the native method has no native implementation at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using upper case field names in criteria rules, i.e. root.get(EntityA_.**ENTITY_B**).

It solved my problem with find bugs warning.
Hope it also be of any help for you.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35151207)